# Showing Jlabels at the same time

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield, conditional-statements

I have a problem, based on my code I can only show 1 jlabel even if there are 1 or more empty JTextfield, I was hoping when 2 or more JTextfield is empty 2 or more jlabel will appear. In my program I have 4 jtextfield and 2 comboboxes each of this has 1 jlabel. How can I improve my code? Thank You in advance for suggestions.

Here is my code:

```
   private void cmdAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

   if(txtFirst.getText().equals("")){
        lblReq1.setVisible(true);
        lblReq2.setVisible(true);
        txtFirst.requestFocusInWindow();
   }
   else if(txtLast.getText().equals("")){
        lblReq1.setVisible(true);
        lblReq3.setVisible(true);
        txtLast.requestFocusInWindow();
   }
   else if(txtUser.getText().equals("")){
        lblReq1.setVisible(true);
        lblReq4.setVisible(true); 
        txtUser.requestFocusInWindow();
   }
   else if(txtPass.getText().equals("")){
        lblReq1.setVisible(true);
        lblReq5.setVisible(true);  
        txtPass.requestFocusInWindow();
   }
   else if(cmbType.getSelectedItem().equals("Select Type")){
        lblReq1.setVisible(true);
        lblReq6.setVisible(true);
   }
   else if(cmbStatus.getSelectedItem().equals("Select Status")){
        lblReq1.setVisible(true);
        lblReq7.setVisible(true);   
   }
   else{}
```

The output of this is when I click the button if there is 2 Jtextfield that is empty 1 jlabel will appear.

Comment: Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so we can test out your problem?

Comment: The output of this is when I click the button if there is 2 Jtextfield that is empty 1 jlabel will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in your `if-else-statement`, it execute only one block of code, because of always only one `JLabel` appears.

Just remove `else` keywords from your method for executing each block.

EDIT: change your code like next:

```
private void cmdAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (txtFirst.getText().isEmpty()) {
        lblReq1.setVisible(true);
        lblReq2.setVisible(true);
        txtFirst.requestFocusInWindow();
    } else {
        //else stuff
    }
    if (txtLast.getText().isEmpty()) {
        lblReq1.setVisible(true);
        lblReq3.setVisible(true);
        txtLast.requestFocusInWindow();
    } 
    if (txtUser.getText().isEmpty()) {
        lblReq1.setVisible(true);
        lblReq4.setVisible(true);
        txtUser.requestFocusInWindow();
    } 
    if (txtPass.getText().isEmpty()) {
        lblReq1.setVisible(true);
        lblReq5.setVisible(true);
        txtPass.requestFocusInWindow();
    } 
    if (cmbType.getSelectedItem().equals("Select Type")) {
        lblReq1.setVisible(true);
        lblReq6.setVisible(true);
    } 
    if (cmbStatus.getSelectedItem().equals("Select Status")) {
        lblReq1.setVisible(true);
        lblReq7.setVisible(true);
    } 
}
```

Comment: can you suggest a condition/s in my if-else-statement so that it will show 2 or more jlabels

Comment: I suggest you to remove each `else` keyword, did you try that?

Comment: inside the else statement there is a code where i add records to the database

Comment: Yes, try that, it helps you.

Comment: it works but when i put a value in the first textbox the empty fields will be saved -_-

Comment: You need to validate your save by another way, may be using some boolean flag.